# SQL*Plus EXIT <variable> type

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a basic script run through SQL*Plus, and I want to pass status codes back to the calling environment via `EXIT <variable>`.

```
DECLARE
        id varchar2(30) := &1 ;
        status varchar(3);
        myvar int := 99 ;
BEGIN
        SELECT code INTO status
        FROM table WHERE index = id;
        myvar := TO_NUMBER(status);

        dbms_output.put_line(status);  -- this works and shows the value I want to see as expected

COMMIT;
END;
/
EXIT myvar
```

My question is what type of variable must I declare to allow it to send back the value of that variable. I have tried `INT`, `NUMBER(2,0)` [ my thinking here is that the precision is less than 255 as I see the  must be a 1 byte value]. However every time I call it I get the following error

```
Usage: { EXIT | QUIT }  [ SUCCESS | FAILURE | WARNING | n |
       <variable> | :<bindvariable> ]  [ COMMIT | ROLLBACK ]
```

I am thinking that I somehow need a 8 bit numeric type. Any suggestions?

My calling environment requires a 2 digit status code which means values in the range 0-255 (8bit) are just perfect.

My calling environment is the `"system()"` function in C and it works perfectly when I hard code values in my script e.g. `EXIT 30` or `EXIT 20`, but `EXIT myvar` doesn't work when I declare `myvar` as `int` or `numeric`, I also tried initializing `myvar` to something like `99`  (`myvar int := 99` ) and it doesn't work.

Comment: It is kind of difficult to debug code you can't see. Anyway, did you try the OUT procedure's parameter? You wouldn't EXIT, but set that parameter's value.

Comment: That usage message is from SQL\*Plus, not PL/SQL. Is your system call to run the `sqlplus` binary, maybe passing a script file name? What will set the variable in your script value?

Comment: I have added code. It all works as expected if I substitute myvar for a number between 0-255I I however need a way to vary the return code so that I can relay the value from the table back to the calling environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [a bind variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm):

```
-- declare as SQL*Plus bind variable
variable myvar number;

-- initialise if relevant; could be done inside your PL/SQL block too
exec :myvar := 99;

DECLARE
  id varchar2(30) := &1;
  status varchar(3);
BEGIN
  SELECT code INTO status
  FROM your_table
  WHERE your_index = id;

   -- use bind variable, note the leading colon
  :myvar := TO_NUMBER(status);
END;
/

-- exit using the bind variable, again note the leading colon
EXIT :myvar
```

[The SQL*Plus documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve023.htm#SQPUG044) shows the allowed exit values.

If I create a dummy table (using valid identifiers) and add a row with index 1 and code 42, calling that as a script from the shell and using `$?` to see the return code (the same as your `system()` call would get) gives:

```
$ sqlplus -l -s usr/pwd@db @your_script 1

old   2:   id varchar2(30) := &1 ;
new   2:   id varchar2(30) := 1 ;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

$ echo $?
42
```

You can also select directly into the bind variable, which isn't directly relevant but could save you a step and a local variable if you aren't using that for anything else. You also don't really need the `id` variable as you can use `&1` directly in your query (though it can be useful to do it this way sometimes), so for your presumably simplified example you could just do:

```
variable myvar number;

BEGIN
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(code)
  INTO :myvar
  FROM your_table
  WHERE your_index = &1;
END;
/

EXIT :myvar
```

---

If you don't actually need to use PL/SQL at all in your script, you could also use the query result directly via the `column ... new_value ...` syntax; this gives you the variable (as opposed to bind variable) option referred to in the usage and docs.:

```
define myvar = 99

column status new_value myvar

SELECT TO_NUMBER(code) AS status
FROM your_table
WHERE your_index = &1;

EXIT myvar
```

Note there is no colon, or indeed ampersand, when using it in the `exit` command. The `define` is only necessary to provide that code if an error occurs; you could use `whenever sqlerror exit 99` instead. Depends how much control you want.

Comment: Thank you ALex works exactly as I want it to!!!! I dont have enough reputation to upvote yet.